# Missing second value memory calculator

Tags: java, calculator, missing-data

My program runs but when I need it to calculate what I need it to do (add, subtract, multiply, divide) it just puts in the value that I typed in and won't do the operation I tell it to do, it just displays the menu again. How do I fix it so it can do the function it needs to do and also loop back to the menu to do another function? (ex. I want to add 2 and 2 together then turn around and multiply 3 and 2)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {            
    Testt calc = new Testt();
    calc.getCurrentValue();
    displayMenu();
}

public static int displayMenu() {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    Testt calc = new Testt();
    int choice;
    do {
        System.out.println("Hello, welcome to the menu");
        System.out.println("Select one of the following items from the menu:");
        System.out.println("1) Add ");
        System.out.println("2) Subtract ");
        System.out.println("3) Multiply ");
        System.out.println("4) Divide ");
        System.out.println("5) Clear ");
        System.out.println("6.Quit");
        System.out.println ("Please choice an option from the menu:");

        choice = input.nextInt();

        if (choice > 6 || choice < 1) {
            System.out.println("Sorry," + choice + " was not an option");
            return displayMenu();
        }

    } while (choice > 6 && choice < 1);

    if (choice == 5) {
        calc.clear();
        return 0;
    } else if (choice == 6) {
        System.out.println("Goodbye! ");
        System.exit(0);
    }

    System.out.println("What is the second number? ");
    double operand2 = input.nextDouble();

    switch (choice) {

    case 1:
        calc.add(operand2);
        break;

    case 2:
        calc.subtract(operand2);
        break;

    case 3:
        calc.multiply(operand2);
        break;

    case 4:
        calc.divide(operand2);
        break;

    }

    return choice;
}

public static double getOperand(String prompt) {

    return 0;
}

private double currentValue;

public double getCurrentValue() {
    System.out.println("The current value is " + currentValue);
    return 0;
}

public void add(double operand2) {
    currentValue = currentValue + operand2;
    getCurrentValue();
}

public void subtract(double operand2) {
    currentValue = operand2 - currentValue;
    getCurrentValue();
}

public void multiply(double operand2) {
    currentValue = operand2 * currentValue;
    getCurrentValue();
}

public void divide(double operand2) {
    if (operand2 == 0) {
        System.out.println("Sorry, you can not divide by 0");
    }
    currentValue = operand2 / currentValue;
    getCurrentValue();

}

public void clear() {
    currentValue = 0;
    getCurrentValue();
}
```

Comment: Not what you asked, but `while (choice > 6 && choice < 1);` is a typo.  This condition is never true, because there's no number that's both more than 6 and less than 1.  You want `||` instead of  `&&`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `getCurrentValue()` you are always returning 0.
You need to return current value.

Also if you want to loop back to same thing you can put all this in `while(true)` loop. like this:

```
   public static int displayMenu() {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        Demo calc = new Demo();
        int choice;
        System.out.println("Hello, welcome to the menu");
        System.out.println("Select one of the following items from the menu:");
        System.out.println("1) Add ");
        System.out.println("2) Subtract ");
        System.out.println("3) Multiply ");
        System.out.println("4) Divide ");
        System.out.println("5) Clear ");
        System.out.println("6.Quit");

        while(true){
            System.out.println ("Please choice an option from the menu:");
            choice = input.nextInt();

            if (choice > 6 || choice < 1) {
                System.out.println("Sorry," + choice + " was not an option");
                continue;
            }

            if (choice == 5) {
                calc.clear();
                return 0;
            } else if (choice == 6) {
                System.out.println("Goodbye! ");
                System.exit(0);
            }

            System.out.println("What is the second number? ");
            double operand2 = input.nextDouble();

            switch (choice) {

                case 1:
                    calc.add(operand2);
                    break;

                case 2:
                    calc.subtract(operand2);
                    break;

                case 3:
                    calc.multiply(operand2);
                    break;

                case 4:
                    calc.divide(operand2);
                    break;

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much! My program is doing what it needs to do now!